# NSTableView with custom rows using cocoa-binding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

First I would like to clear that I am well aware of these:

i. Cocoa-binding for cell / view based table view, with same controls on all the rows.

ii. Programmatically having a table view with different controls in rows.

But I am stuck while using binding to  create a table view where I have 2 types of controls for some rows. I can achieve this using programming by creating button cell / text cell and using `setDataCell:`.

Is this possible to achieve by IB cocoa-binding? If so how, as in the Binding's Inspector it doesn't have features others than value, editable, hidden, size and text color etc.

*Another question:*

Can I have two cell views so that on some condition I could show one after another?

Comment: You may need to clarify the question.  You have a rowview with 2 control types in IB and you want to bind some model objects to them?  Or you want some decisions made about whether they're displayed?  You can bind the hidden property if you create a view with two controls and only want one shown depending on the model object type represented by the row.

Comment: @stevesliva: Your 2nd one is my requirement. I can do hide/show but I feel this is not the best way.